# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uwsgi'

Tags: python-3.x, import, uwsgi

I need to use the uwsgi cron interface, I am using python3.6 virtual environment, installed uwsgi using `pip install uwsgi`, also installed the python36-devel using `sudo yum install python36-devel`

My Environment
Centos 7
python 36
uWSGI==2.0.18

I imported in my pyramid project
like 
`import uwsgi`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uwsgi'
```

Comment: I don't think you can import `uwsgi` in your python script. See here https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1073

Comment: So If I need to use the cron interface of uwsgi any workaround for that